# returning a self executing function (IIFE) from another function

Tags: javascript

```
(function($) {

    var foo = (function(){

        //some functions

    })();

    // I can access foo here
    var f = new foo();

})(jQuery);

// But obviously not here since it's in another scope
```

How do I return `foo` to the window scope, so that it can be accessed outside of the outer IIFE? I've tried `return foo;` but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set it as a window property:

```
(function($) {

    var foo = (function() {

        // some functions

    })();

    window.foo = foo;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

})(jQuery);

foo();
```

However, setting global objects as properties of the `window` object is typically looked down upon. Perhaps you can emulate this ability by managing your own custom "global" object. For example:

```
var global = {};

(function($) {

    global.foo = (function() {

        // define

    })();

})(jQuery);

global.foo();
```

That way you won't have name clashes when dealing with a variety of scopes and objects.

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I didn't think of that :)

Comment: Regarding your second code snippet; it would still mean that i get window.global.foo, right? Not much of a difference, imo.

Comment: @Johan No you wouldn't, it would just be regarded as `global`. If I had defined it without the `var` keyword it would've become a global variable on the window object. Not in this case though.

Comment: what about wrapping the outer IIFE in a variable and return foo inside. Then access it by the new variable.foo?

Comment: @David What are you talking about? Anything defined in the global scope, with or without `var`, adds a property to `window` as well. And anything added to `window` is also available by the property name (without `window.`). Either way, it's debatable to use one huge object (although I use and recommend it) compared to multiple global things

Comment: @Ian Okay I may be mistaken, but why am I getting `undefined` here - http://jsfiddle.net/WADk6/

Comment: @David That's because you never define `a` or `window.a`. Why are you checking for **a**? http://jsfiddle.net/TUW6X/

Comment: @David Look at the top left of your fiddle setup. It's set to run `onLoad`. So defining `var global = {};` in that scenario defines a `global` variable locally in the `onload` method of the `window`. If you look at the fiddle in my last comment, it runs in `<head>` - it's actually in the global scope.

Comment: It's ok to READ properties from outer scopes, but WRITING them from inner and hidden scopes is in general a bad taste programming. You'll end up not knowing what comes from where and when was created. Using a consistent constructing approach like the one I've written keeps you from esoteric guessing at the long term.

Answer (score 1):

Using global properties is a express ticket to spaghetti code. Your whole application should live in as few elements in the global object as possible, ideally only one.

This is much more elegant and safe at the long term.

```
var MYAPP = {}; //declaring with var is not necessary here, but it's good to keep constant.

MYAPP = (function($, MYAPP) {

    var foo = (function(){

        //some functions

    })();

    // enrich your object
    MYAPP.foo = foo;
    return MYAPP;

})(jQuery, MYAPP);
```

And then you can use your "enriched" MYAPP object.

```
MAYPP.foo();
```

A pattern similar to this is suggested by JavaScript's God: Douglas Crockford.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my case I know that it will only be one property on the window object though. Does it really matter if its `MYAPP` or `foo`? I mean, it will be at least one property attached to `window` either way, right?

Comment: There has to be one property of `window` at least. If you only need that one of course it is not problem, but in programming these little "i'll only do it once" always come back to you as your programme grows and kick you in the balls =). Even if you only need foo, I would declare `var foo;` in the global and assign it from the return from the autoexecuting function. This way you'll know where it comes from even if your programme is 5k lines long. Don't allow for strange dependencies, keep it clean.